# How to make my KML/KMZ accessible to the public

Tags: kml, google-maps-api, kmz, google-drive

I created a basic web dashboard with MVC 4 that has a Google Map open on it. I have a KMZ file I made with ArcGIS desktop of a road in a Google Drive folder that i made publicly available so that i could take the URL of my file and implement that in MVC to overlay the KMZ file onto the Google Map, However when i run the process the dashboard opens up the Google Map on the correct spot however there is no shape file. The images attached show the code in MVC 4 that generates the Web dashboard, and the KMZ file sitting in the Google drive Folder. I am wondering if maybe there is not a problem with my script or if Google drive is the problem.

This is the URL to the KML: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4_TJdssPL1RRC13MTlzbjVPWHM/edit?usp=sharing

I am using MVC 4 and Google Javascript API v3

[image]

[image]

Comment: How large is the KML?

Comment: @Mapperz it is 40 kb

Comment: Can we test the url for the KML? - I know google only like to display KML over thier own domain (no cross domain access)

Comment: @Mapperz yes yes absolutely

Comment: can you post the 'long' url in your question please.

Comment: @Mapperz I just posted it into the question

Comment: @Mapperz i really need to you to get back on this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own local server, kml file needs an http:// and then make sure the dashboard runs in firefox, google chrome could not display the data.

Answer (score 0):

the way it become accessible in html:

1. make your kml/kmz file can be accessed by public

   right click -> share -> advanced -> who has accesse - Public
2. then use drive for hosting your file
   http://googledrive.com/host/

in your case the item ID is

> 0B4_TJdssPL1RRC13MTlzbjVPWHM

so change the kml address in your HTML  become :

> https://googledrive.com/host/0B4_TJdssPL1RRC13MTlzbjVPWHM